# SimpleMembership API connectionStringName error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use [SimpleMembership](http://anderly.com/2011/05/18/simplemembership-mvc3-1-1-published/) in my MVC 3 application. However I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled
>   by user code. Unable to find the
>   requested .Net Framework Data
>   Provider.  It may not be installed.

I'm using EF and the framework is obviously there since my app works perfect without the SimpleMembership API

Here is the Set Up in the Web config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="SeniorProjectModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.SeniorProjectModel.csdl|res://*/Models.SeniorProjectModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.SeniorProjectModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=GOGOTOPPY;Initial Catalog=SPMT;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And heres how it looks in the in the Membership file in the App_Start folder:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(connectionStringName: "SeniorProjectModelContainer", userTableName: "Users", userIdColumn: "UserId", userNameColumn: "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Update:
```

The quick work around was to take the metadata part out of the connection string and change the provider name to the SqlClient so it looks similar to this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Membership" connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Database=datebaseName;User ID=idName;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Is there any downside of the connection string looking like this?

Comment: your "update" workaround worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you installed simplemembership but try doing it the nuget way for example,
http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/SimpleMembership.Mvc3

Comment: I did use nuget to install simplemembership, however I did find a work around that I show in the Edited section